# Is CSS3background-image:url() auto change the size of images?

Tags: css, background-image

I want to put this picture as background

```
https://i.ibb.co/GCCdy8t/womens.png
```

It's 800*490,so I make a box which is 800px*490px

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .background-image{
            width: 800px;
            height: 490px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/GCCdy8t/womens.png');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background-image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but the picture doesn't fit my box,I inspected this element and found the size of picture is 180*180,how can I make them fit each other

Comment: Your code works. The only thing that I could get to happen was that the image loaded extremely slowly on the first load, possibly due to it linking to a page that has some inline styling done including a background-color transition for some reason. Have you tried saving the image to another host and linking it so there's no styling being applied while the image is being loaded into your code?

Comment: I did,I put the picture on my computer and it works well. How can I solve this problem

Comment: You need to host the image somewhere else. That site you're hosting it from is applying inline styling and it's probably causing loading issues --most likely the transition which doesn't even affect the image you have --  which is why you think your image is smaller than it actually is. At one point when I tried your code, it stopped loading altogether for about 5 seconds and then completed itself. You could try a site like Imgur but when you go to publish your site you'll probably have a media folder of some kind anyway that you can direct link to.

Comment: Thank you for your help , I thought it was my code problem.I'll try your solution ❥(^_-)

Comment: Yeah, that loads instantly and at the specific size. Imgur isn't doing anything with it other than hosting it.

Comment: ```background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/V0DMXPC.png");```